# getting .index() position from whole document?

Tags: jquery

at the moment I have

```
alert('Index: ' + $(this).index());
```

on a click event, it alerts the elements current position but only inside its parent element right? how could i use .index() to find the position from the whole document?

Thank you,

Steve,

Comment: What do you mean by "position from the whole document"? Document is a tree structure, not a flat array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you could call:

```
$('*').index($(this));
```

or to see which (example, 'img') it is...

```
$('img').index($(this));
```

Comment: `$('body *').index(...)` might give more "sensible" results.

Comment: @steveax I think you might be right. I did some experimenting in your Fiddle, and see what you mean. However, I just implemented my way into my program and got desirable results... However, I got a negative number using my way in your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZXsXk/1/